# Detect changes in ObjectSet in Entity Framework 4.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to check if there is anything changes in a table in EF 4.0 with the following code:

```
var a = context.Users.GetHashCode();

AddNewUser();

context.SaveChanges();

var b = context.Users.GetHashCode();
```

a == b, I don't know why?

Any helps would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GetHashCode` has absolutelly [different usage](http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2008/07/05/explaining-gethashcode-method/). You can't detect changes in `ObjectSet` because it is entry point to related database table(s). You can detect changes prepared in `ObjectContext` but only before you accept changes (default `SaveChanges` also accept changes). To get changes from `ObjectContext` use:

```
context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my question, what if I want to check table changes?

Comment: @NVA: Why do you want it? First of all think about doing the same in SQL.

Comment: I want to make a lot of changes inside a TransactionScope and if 1 change failed then all changes made before to the db will be rollback.

Comment: @NVA: That is direct functionality of `TransactionScope`. You don't need to detect changes manually. You simply need to throw exception when failure occures or dispose scope without calling `Complete` method.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible that GetHashCode is not considering the real content of the items of the ObjectSet, can't you simply check the count in your case or check the changed property?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply but I'm still finding a way to check the state of ObjectSet without using GetHashCode()

Comment: what happens if you call context.DetectChanges() after your AddNewUser() method call?